# How do I express three items gracefully?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, punctuation, conjunctions, lists

If you have two things, you can say:

> One thing is A, the other is B.

But is there any word group to describe three things that I have? I can only say with my poor English skills:

> There are three things, one is A, one is B, one is C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways of mentioning the three things.

A direct parallel to the first example sentence in the question is actually different from the second example sentence:

- One thing is A, another is B, and the third is C.

Alternatively, you can introduce the list items with a colon or dash:

- There are three things: A, B, and C.
- There are three things—A, B, and C.

Perhaps the simplest and most direct construction follows:

- Those things are A, B, and C.